# OpenAI API: How do I set the organization ID?

Tags: openai-api

I'm trying to create a support bot.

When I try to use OpenAI I always get the following error:

> Rate limit reached for text-embedding-ada-002 in organization org-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> on requests per min (RPM): Limit 3, Used 3, Requested 1.

I think this is because I didn't set my organization ID from the paid Team subscription, where the rate limit shouldn't be reached.

How can I set the organization ID?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/production-best-practices/setting-up-your-organization):

> Users who belong to multiple organizations can **[pass a header](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/requesting-organization) to
> specify which organization is used for an API request**. Usage from
> these API requests will count against the specified organization's
> quota. If no header is provided, the [default organization](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys) will be
> billed. You can change your default organization in your [user
> settings](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys).

### Python

```
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
  organization = 'org-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
)
```

### Node.js

```
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI({
  organization: 'org-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
});
```

### cURL

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/models \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -H "OpenAI-Organization: org-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```